# meaning of "gets a shot" and "get it on target"

Tags: meaning-in-context, informal-language

I don't understand what "get" means in this sentence because it has a lot of meanings. Could you explain?

> 68' Chance for Leeds!
> Gelhardt **gets** a shot away from the edge of the box but he can't
> **get** it on target.
> Both sides knocking on the door here.

[Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/live/article-11157257/Leeds-vs-Everton-Premier-League-2022-23-Live-Result.html?s=08)

Answer (score 2):

There are really only two meanings of get, and this sentence contains both.

1. The first meaning is to receive something, or to be given something.

*Gelhardt gets a shot away from the edge of the box....*

Gelhardt is given [the opportunity to take] a shot away from the edge of the box.

2. The second meaning is to achieve or attain something.

*... he can't get it on target*

"it" refers to "aim", so he can't achieve enough aim to hit the target.

Comment: Seems to me that both usages here are of the second meaning. “gets a shot away” = launches the ball; “get it on target” = score a goal with that shot.

Comment: Different interpretation. I read it as "gets a shot", "away from the edge of the box".